# How to create html list use marionette?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, marionette

- Slide View
- Select 1

  - Sub Select 1
  - Sub Select 2
  - Sub Select 3
- Select 2

  - Sub Select 1
  - Sub Select 2
  - Sub Select 3
- Select 3

  - Sub Select 1
  - Sub Select 2
  - Sub Select 3

Please create to me a simple above output use marionette.

here below i use marionette coding

```
var APP = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

APP.addRegions({
    appMain:"#main"
});

APP.module("APP",function(module, app, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
    module.title = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    module.titles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:module.title
    });

    module.subtitle = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    module.subtitles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:module.subtitle
    });

    module.iView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName:"li",
        template:"#temp-itemview"
    });

    module.csView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        template:"#temp-compositeview",
        childView:module.iView,
        itemViewContainer:"ul",
        initialize:function(){
            this.collection = this.model.get('subtitles');
        }
    });

    module.collView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        childView:module.csView
    });

    module.addInitializer(function(){
        var array = [   {title:"Show 1",array:[{title:"Sub Show 1"},{title:"Sub Show 2"},{title:"Sub Show 3"}]}, 
                        {title:"Show 2",array:[{title:"Sub Show 1"},{title:"Sub Show 2"},{title:"Sub Show 3"}]}, 
                        {title:"Show 3",array:[{title:"Sub Show 1"},{title:"Sub Show 2"},{title:"Sub Show 3"}]}];
        var titles = new module.titles(array);

        titles.each(function(title){
            var array = title.get('array');
            var subtitles = new module.subtitles(array);
            title.set("subtitles",subtitles);
        });

        var superView = new module.collView({
            collection:titles
        });

        APP.appMain.show(superView);
    });
});

APP.start();
```

html

```
<script type="text/template" id="temp-itemview">
    <%= title %>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="temp-compositeview">
    <ul></ul>
</script>
```

Output is not clear.Please correct

Comment: I dnt know how to create lists inside lists use marionette. Can give me simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is inspired from the [Derick Bailey's post](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/). The following one is adapted to `backbone.marionette` version 2.2.1:

---

```
<div id="tree"></div>

<script id="nodeTemplate" type="text/template">
    <li><%= nodeName %></li>
</script>
```

---

```
app = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

app.addRegions({
    mainRegion: "#tree"
});

var TreeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#nodeTemplate",    
    tagName: "ul",
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection = this.model.nodes;
    },
});

var TreeRoot = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    childView: TreeView
});
```

---

```
treeData = [
    {nodeName: "Slide View"},
    {nodeName: "Select 1", 
     nodes: [
         {nodeName: "Sub Select 11"},
         {nodeName: "Sub Select 12"},
         {nodeName: "Sub Select 13"}
     ]},
    {nodeName: "Select 2", 
     nodes: [
         {nodeName: "Sub Select 21"},
         {nodeName: "Sub Select 22"},
         {nodeName: "Sub Select 23"}
     ]},
    {nodeName: "Select 3", 
     nodes: [
         {nodeName: "Sub Select 31"},
         {nodeName: "Sub Select 32"},
         {nodeName: "Sub Select 33"}
     ]},
];

TreeNode = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        var nodes = this.get("nodes");
        if (nodes){
            this.nodes = new TreeNodeCollection(nodes);
            this.unset("nodes");
        }
    }        
});

TreeNodeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TreeNode
});

app.addInitializer(function(options){
    var treeView = new TreeRoot({
          collection: options.tree
    });
    app.mainRegion.show(treeView);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var tree = new TreeNodeCollection(treeData);
    app.start({tree: tree});
});
```

---

Check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/6j2q4g92/1/), to see how it works. Please,pay attention to the external resources.

You can read [Derick Bailey's post](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/) for explication and details. If you want to understand something, or if you want me to adapt this solution to yours, I mean by putting the same variables names, etc. just let me know. I'll be very pleased to help.

Hope it's useful!

Comment: Thank you so must. Working fine. But no need appendHtml call.

Comment: My pleasure! You are absolutely right. No need for appendHtml. I updated the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You would use the Marionette Composite View for this: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md

You want to set the collection for each view and specify a childViewContainer (a jquery selector). If you set a collection for a composite view it will use the same view to render the children in that collection.

You can specify a childView, but I normally don't set that attribute as it should be recursively calling the same view.

Comment: Looks good, you could probably remove the appendHtml call and use childViewContainer:'li:first' instead